# adding prefixes to libs during gradle maven publishing

Tags: gradle, maven-publish

I setup the next configuration for multiproject build:

```
allprojects {
  apply plugin: 'maven-publish'

  repositories {
    mavenCentral()        
  }
}
subprojects {
  apply plugin: 'java'

  sourceCompatibility = 1.8
  targetCompatibility = 1.8

  version = rootProject.version
  group = rootProject.group

  archivesBaseName = "PREFIX-${it.name}"
}
```

But prefix is applied only to built artifacts and not when i execute publish task. Is there a way to configure publishing with prefix?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In accordance with "[Identity values in the generated POM](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/publishing_maven.html#sec:identity_values_in_the_generated_pom)", next configuration should works:

```
subprojects { project ->
...
    publishing {
        publications {
            maven(MavenPublication) {
                artifactId "PREFIX-${project.name}"
                from components.java
            }
        }
    }  
}
```

Comment: is there an approach to change only lib name, but not artifact id?

Comment: I dont't think it makes sense. The maven's naming convention [1]  requires that name of the artifact and name of the lib should be the same. [1]: https://maven.apache.org/guides/mini/guide-naming-conventions.html